# R ; `geom_histogram` whya re my bars not starting at 0?

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

So I was hoping to plot a histogram with a log10 y axis, like this;

```
plot_norm <- ggplot(data, aes(predictions, fill=flavour, colour=flavour)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(y=..density..), breaks=seq(0,1.1,0.05), alpha=0.2, lwd=0.4) +
  scale_y_log10()
```

But what I am getting out looks like this;
[image: The bars down start from zero...]

How can I get the bars to start from 0 and go up?

Comment: Look at the output of `log(0)`. It's generally not reasonable to plot a histogram with log-transformed density.

Comment: @Roland Well I get that a log a number less that 1 is negative, but my y axis dosn't have negative values on it, the values listed there are the true density, which is exactly what I want. I don't see how it's unreasonable to plot provided none of my bars is zero?

Comment: Where, on your log-transformed axis, do you imagine 0 is? It's clearly not at `1e0`. Your next label down is `1e-3`, still not 0. If you went down that far again, you'd get to `1e-6`, still not 0. Go down that far 100 times more, you'll be at `1e-300`, still not 0...

Comment: We use histograms to get an idea of the distribution of the data. It's difficult to infer that accurately if you log-transform the density.

Comment: @Gregor  ok, yeh I see what you and Roland mean, I cannot have zero. Unfortunately, the format of the plot is not my idea. I am replicating a histogram of density with a log scale from someone else's paper. So I guess what I need is to start the bars from an arbitrary negative value, and then only show the end points.

Comment: Sorry you're having to do that. A better way to visualize the data might be to do two density plots, one of all the data you show, and another zoomed in on the x-axis to exclude those two end bars that dominate everything else. That way you could communicate more accurately (a) how much those endpoints dominate the distribution, but still convey (b) the distribution of the middle.

Comment: As you proceed with the log-scale, definitely experiment with different arbitrary values to set to 0 - observe how much you can manipulate the look of the plot by picking different values, and understand that you could tell very different stories based on which values you picked. And be skeptical of authors who do that. They are warping their data a specific way to tell a specific story.

Comment: Drawing the "0" line at the bottom of your current graph, you can tell that the end bars are big, but you don't get the impression that they are thousands to millilons times bigger than the others. And the farther down you set the 0, the more similar everything looks...

Comment: SO just revisiting this, in case anyone else is in the same position; the answer was to use pythons `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` which will do exactly this.